# Connecting to wi-fi through terminal

Tags: networking, 20.04

When suspending my laptop it takes a while for any WI-fi's to get detected. Are there any ways i can search for and connect to a WI-fi faster through the terminal?

I'm pretty new to linux so ask for any info needed.

Comment: What is a while 5 seconds 30 mins? I assume you mean wake from suspend although that is not what the question says. There is not enough info here to see what the undefined delay is being caused by.

Comment: Yes sorry title is misleading. After waking up my laptop back on after suspension, it takes maybe 30 seconds to 1 minute for it to find any available wifi networks.

Comment: That is not unusual. Please update the question with this info with edit and if the title is wring edit that as well.

Comment: @David Hej David! Skulle jag möjligtvis kunna komma i kontakt med dig någonstans? :)

Comment: why would you need to do that?

Comment: @David Jag är en universitetsstudent som pluggar IT och har precis börjat använda Ubuntu, men hade gärna haft någon som jag kan fråga om hjälp när det behövs. Eller om tips och råd! :)